# AngularJS checkbox dynamic ng-true-value expression

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to build a calculator for daycare prices in Angular.

Every location in the company franchise has separate prices for every day. So my thinking was to build a form, with first a select that allows you to select the location, then a series of checkboxes for the days.

I'm having trouble with ng-true-value in the checkboxes selecting the correct prices from my json file.

**UPDATE:** Added Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MDmrqaH1VzLBzjd5eHgT?p=preview

Consider this code:

```
        <p class="kind_section">Choose location</p>
        <select ng-model="formData.location" ng-options="location.title for location in data.bso"></select>

        <p class="kind_section">Select days</p>

        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.day.mon" ng-change="calculatePrice()" ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.monday}}" ng-false-value="0">Ma
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.day.tue" ng-change="calculatePrice()" ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.tuesday}}" ng-false-value="0">Di<br />
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.day.wed" ng-change="calculatePrice()" ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.wednesday}}" ng-false-value="0">Wo
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.day.thu" ng-change="calculatePrice()" ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.thursday}}" ng-false-value="0">Do<br />
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.day.fri" ng-change="calculatePrice()" ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.friday}}" ng-false-value="0">Vr
```

First the select sets formData with a location ID, then I want to use this ID to select the day prices for the matching location and set those to ng-true-value.

I'm using `ng-true-value="{{data.bso[formData.location.ID].prices.monday}}"` for this. This doesn't work.

When I set the ID manually like `ng-true-value="{{data.bso[0].prices.monday}}"` it does work. Why is the result of the select not being picked up by ng-true-value?

This is my json file:

```
  $scope.data = {
                "bso": [
                  {
                    "ID": 0,
                    "title": "Locatie 1",
                    "prices": {
                        "monday": 130,
                        "tuesday": 130,
                        "wednesday": 200,
                        "thursday":130,
                        "friday": 130
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "ID": 1,
                    "title": "Locatie 2",
                    "prices": {
                        "monday": 430,
                        "tuesday": 530,
                        "wednesday": 600,
                        "thursday":990,
                        "friday": 730
                    }
                  }
                ]
              };
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? There was a change on `ngTrueValue` in the last one.

Comment: I'm using v1.3.0 Beta.13

Comment: Use an `ng-change` to see if the model is being updated at all. Does the `formData` object exist in your scope? `ng-select` uses a child scope.

Comment: It does update.. I'm going to provide a Plunkr, hold on

Comment: AFAIK, the ng-true-value parse the given expression only once. And the `formData.location.ID` surely is still undefined at the time the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems `ng-true-value` does not accept non-constant expressions. From the [docs(v1.3.0)](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/constexpr):

*Some attributes used in conjunction with ngModel (such as ngTrueValue or ngFalseValue) will only accept constant expressions.*

*Examples using constant expressions include:*

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-true-value="'truthyValue'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-false-value="0">
```

*Examples of non-constant expressions include:*

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-true-value="someValue">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-false-value="{foo: someScopeValue}">
```

An ideal workaround probably would be calling a  Controller method on `ng-click` or `ng-change` inside which you can analyse all the checkboxes for truthy or non-truthy values.

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've just added a Plunkr as well: http://plnkr.co/edit/MDmrqaH1VzLBzjd5eHgT?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to delay the creation of the checkbox until the value is ready (on scope or whatever).

In my case I was loading a value via http that wasn't on the scope when the checkbox was created. So I just wrapped it in an ng-if.

```
          <div class="checkbox" ng-if="viewData.conditionId != undefined">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{'\''+ viewData.conditionId + '\''}}" ng-false-value="undefined" ng-model="model.conditionId" required />
              I agree
            </label>
          </div>
```

Which worked perfectly for my scenario. Yours is a bit different but the same principal should apply - delay creation of the checkbox until you *know* the value being bound is there.

And yes the stupid quotation marks seem to be necessary.

Comment: you may be able to simplify quotes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29019232/4297364

Comment: This worked for me as well, although I didn't need the quotation marks because the expressions I wanted were true/false, rather than strings.

Answer (score 2):

Expression in the ng-true-value will be evaluated only once, so it won't be dynamic.

One alternative approach is to calculate the values in ng-change callback instead.

Please see my fork http://plnkr.co/edit/9zYS3OZ0sSkXX9rHwcgv?p=preview for the full example.

In html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDays.monday" ng-change="calculatePrice()" /> Mon
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDays.tuesday" ng-change="calculatePrice()" /> Tue            <br />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDays.wednesday" ng-change="calculatePrice()" /> Wed
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDays.thursday" ng-change="calculatePrice()" /> Thu            <br />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDays.friday" ng-change="calculatePrice()" /> Fri
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(){
  $scope.formData.location.day = {};

  angular.forEach($scope.selectedDays, function (selected, day) {
    if (selected) {
      $scope.formData.location.day[day.slice(0, 3)] = $scope.data.bso[$scope.formData.location.ID].prices[day];
    }
  });
}

$scope.selectedDays = {};
```