# NG-True-Value: Only accepts String literals?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get the ng-true-value directive to work with expressions or objects:

I tried:

```
   ng-true-value={{type}}
   ng-true-value="type"
   ng-true-value="{{type}}"
```

But none of these seem to work. Can Angular's ng-true-value directive only accept string literals?

Comment: Really not happy about this: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/67999-feature-ngtruevalue-should-accept-non-string-values

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/24758681/4663869

Answer (score 3):

`ng-true-value` does not accept non-constant expressions. Your question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758681/angularjs-checkbox-dynamic-ng-true-value-expression).

For string values in ng-*, surround it in single quotes, like so:

```
ng-true-value=" 'type' "
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question?

Comment: I am looking for a solution to evaluate expressions as ng-true-value.