# AngularJS setting ng-model to Null and still have a $valid form

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using a nullable Date Time in a check box in angular

In my model

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp { get; set; }
```

In my html form named name="memberInfoForm"

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp"
       ng-checked="memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp != null"
       ng-true-value="{{getDatetime()}}"
       ng-false-value="{{null}}">
```

I have a button which is disabled anytime I click the check box to set it to the current date time then click it again to set it back to null the form is becoming invalid. I tried setting the ng-false-value="{{"null"}}" (no success) any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Below is my button that checks for form validity if that gives any more insight.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="!memberInfoForm.$valid" ng-click="memberInfoForm.$valid && SaveUserInformation()">Save Personal Information</button>
```

Comment: Take a look here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758681/angularjs-checkbox-dynamic-ng-true-value-expression I don't think `ng-true-value` can be a function.

Comment: Maybe try to inspect the memberInfo.Form object in dev tools.  I think there is a $error array that you can traverse to find the offending element and reason

Comment: Thanks for the response @jcc the ng-true-value is working with the function. It's when I set the check box to false (makeing memberUnreachableDateTimeStamp null) that the form becomes invalid.

Comment: @brewsky i'll take a look into $error maybe that will give me a fix. Appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I played with things for a little bit longer and came up with the following solution.

In my Controller I created a function called UpdateMemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp and a new scope variable memberUnreachable

```
$scope.memberUnreachable;
$scope.UpdateMemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp = function (checked) {
    if (checked)
    {
        $scope.memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp = new Date();
        $scope.memberUnreachable = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp = null;
        $scope.memberUnreachable = false;
    }
};
```

In my HTML

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="memberUnreachable"
       ng-checked="memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp != null"
       ng-click="UpdateMemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp(memberUnreachable)" />
```

Seems to work with setting the nullable datetime memberInformation.Details.MemberUnreachableDateTimeStamp to null and keeps my form valid when doing so. There might be a cleaner solution so if you think of one please let me know.